# How do I create an Elm Lang event when scrolling?

Tags: html, events, scroll, elm, mousewheel

I want to know when the user scroll in my webpage. How do I create an Elm event after each time a user scrolls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost certainly want to use a [`port`](https://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/ports.html) to create the scroll event. `Wheel` cacn have some strange side effects.

It is also recommend to ignore some of the scroll events otherwise your website will generate thousands of events per minute. This is done with the `ticking` variable below and `requestAnimationFrame`. Change `ticking > 5` to any int you would like depending on your desired responsiveness.

```js
var ticking = 0;
window.addEventListener("scroll", function (event) {
    if (ticking > 5) {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        app.ports.recvScroll.send();
        ticking = 0;
      });
    }
    ticking += 1;
});
```

`recvScroll` is the name of the port in the related elm code. But you can name it whatever you would like.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to create an event listener on the div. Use the Html.Events [on](https://elm.pravdomil.com/packages/?package=elm%2Fhtml&module=Html.Events#on) to create a custom event listener.

That html event then needs to be decoded into an Elm event. like this:

`on "wheel" (Decode.succeed Scroll)` where `Scroll` is a `Msg`, it can be any of you app's `Msg`s. This can be applied to any div. For example here is an implementation with `Elm-UI` to detect a scroll anywhere in the webpage.

```
import Html.Events exposing (on)
import Json.Decode as Decode

view model =
    layout
        [ htmlAttribute <| on "wheel" (Decode.succeed Scroll)
        ]
    <|
        column []
            [
               ~~~ snip
            ]
```

Comment: You probably want to handle the `scroll` event, rather than the `wheel` event. Alternatively, you could call [`Browser.Dom.getViewport`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/browser/latest/Browser-Dom#getViewport) in an interval subscription and check if it changed.

Comment: I tried using the `scroll` event before the `wheel` event, and `scroll` just didn't create any events. I'm not sure if I am the problem, or if `scroll` just wasn't right for my use case?

Comment: [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event)
"Note: Don't confuse the `wheel` event with the `scroll` event. The default action of a `wheel` event is implementation-specific, and doesn't necessarily dispatch a `scroll` event. Even when it does, the `delta*` values in the `wheel` event don't necessarily reflect the content's scrolling direction. Therefore, do not rely on the `wheel` event's `delta*` properties to get the scrolling direction. Instead, detect value changes of `scrollLeft` and `scrollTop` of the target in the `scroll` event."

Comment: Maybe the element you have the event on isn't the element that's scrolling?

Comment: Only scrollable elements will dispatch the scroll event, that is `window`/`document` and all HTML elements that have their heights set and CSS `overflow` set to `scroll`.